# using emberjs new-router-V3 and #with helper to access events defined in a different route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have this working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3ry/1/)**. The **EmBlog.PostsEditRoute** has a **destroyPost event** which I want to call with an **action helper** in the 'post/show.hbs' which is the template for the **EmBlog.PostsShowRoute**.

I am using **#with helper to change scope in the template** as suggested **[here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/993)**. It doesn't destroy the object and throws no error.

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
   {{#with EmBlog.PostsEditController}}
      <a href='#' {{action destroyPost this}}> Destroy</a>
   {{/with}}
 </script>

 EmBlog.PostsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

 });

 EmBlog.PostsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
      destroyPost: function(context) {
       var post = context.get('content'); 
        post.deleteRecord();
        post.get('store').commit();
        this.transitionTo('posts');
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is basically because you have to define your event handler in the `EmBlog.PostsShowRoute` or in the PostsRoute if you want it to be accessible in an other PostsXXX view. see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/ for details.

(the use of the #with helper here seems wrong here BTW, as your reference is about something quite old). I would simply do

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
  <a {{action destroyPost content}}> Destroy</a>
</script>
```

Here is the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn3ry/4/

Note that when you try to destroy a post which is in the fixtures, it reappears when you transition to posts/index. This is simply because the post is not destroyed in the fixtures, and when entering to the PostIndexRoute, App.Post.find() will reload it again.

Comment: many thanks for answering my question again. I hope the snow fall was not too bad on your way home yesterday.

Comment: ;) No problem, I learn almost every time I answer. For the snow, it was good enough to take the car and go to restaurant :p